# How do I get ActionBar attribute in my class [android]

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Simple question how do I use getDisplayOptions() of action bar? I want to maintain the state of action bar as I am flipping my view with some custom view. So before bringing my view I am storing my action bar state, so that I revert back to original state when my view is removed. I set few setting to my action bar like

```
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

So when I remove my view I want to revert back these setting. But I don't see any method like `actionBar.isDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` etc in API. Although I see actionBar.getDisplayOptions(). But don't know how to use it. Can any body help me achieving this.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Simple question how do I use getDisplayOptions() of action bar?

Whenever you change the display options in the `ActionBar`, `ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(int options, int mask)` is called internally to pair that display option with the corresponding bitmask.

For instance, when `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` is called, internally `ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(int options, int mask)` is called like this:

```
setDisplayOptions(showHomeAsUp ? DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP : 0, DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

So, if you want to check to see if particular display option is enabled, you just compare that mask to `0` using a bitwise operation.

```
// Retrieve the current set of display options
final int displayOptions = actionBar.getDisplayOptions();
// Determine which display options are enabled
final boolean isShowHomeEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME) != 0;
final boolean isHomeAsUpEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP) != 0;
final boolean isShowTitleEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE) != 0;
final boolean isUseLogoEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO) != 0;
final boolean isShowCustomEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM) != 0;
```

A complete example might be something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    // Retrieve the current set of display options
    final int displayOptions = actionBar.getDisplayOptions();
    // Determine which display options are enabled
    final boolean isShowHomeEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME) != 0;
    final boolean isHomeAsUpEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP) != 0;
    final boolean isShowTitleEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE) != 0;
    final boolean isUseLogoEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO) != 0;
    final boolean isShowCustomEnabled = (displayOptions & ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM) != 0;

    System.out.println("show home: " + isShowHomeEnabled);
    System.out.println("home as up: " + isHomeAsUpEnabled);
    System.out.println("show title: " + isShowTitleEnabled);
    System.out.println("use logo: " + isUseLogoEnabled);
    System.out.println("show custom: " + isShowCustomEnabled);
}
```

Which would print:

```
show home: false
home as up: true
show title: false
use logo: true
show custom: false
```

Comment: Great Awesome Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation. Works for me.