# How to check if Up button enabled?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

Some where in code I add

```
ActionBar ab = ((AuthActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
      ab.hide();
      ab.show();
      ab.setTitle(R.string.auth_tt_title);
      ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Later, I add fiew fragments one of which may change title and display home button.Thus, I wat to save state for ActionBar before I made changes, to be able to restore it asfter fragment will be gone.
I can get title as

```
private String getAbStatus(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    String title="";
    boolean visible;
    ActionBar ab = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
      if (ab.getTitle() != null) title = ab.getTitle().toString();
    }
    return title;
  }
```

But how can I get state of HomeAsUp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

```
if (ab.getDisplayOptions() & ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP != 0) {}
```

Long answer here: [How do I get ActionBar attribute in my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794590/how-do-i-get-actionbar-attribute-in-my-class-android)